# How to connect ODBC Database in Cakephp 4.4

Tags: cakephp, odbc

How can I configure odbc database in cake 4.4. Currently default cakephp didn't have ODBC Driver.

I tried using this plugin https://github.com/mikeweb85/cakephp-odbc but still not working.

I need guide to connect ODBC (sybase) in cakephp 4.4 and which driver i need to download.

Thank you in advance.